# SQL output - include columns from different tables with the same timestamp

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL query that queries multiple tables.
Keeping the same timestamp, I wish the output to contain the column from both the tables relating to the particular timestamp. The following code produces two separate tables.

```
SELECT 
    [2000823317].[TimeStamp], 
    [2000823317].[E_Total_Last] as "2000823317_E_Total_Last"
FROM

[LIBPV_WB].[AD\30186656].[2000823317] 

WHERE 
 [2000823317].[TimeStamp] BETWEEN '2010-12-31 19:00:00' AND '2010-12-31 19:05:00' or
 [2000823317].[TimeStamp] BETWEEN '2011-12-31 19:00:00' AND '2011-12-31 19:05:00' or
 [2000823317].[TimeStamp] BETWEEN '2012-12-31 19:00:00' AND '2012-12-31 19:05:00' or
 [2000823317].[TimeStamp] BETWEEN '2013-12-31 19:00:00' AND '2013-12-31 19:05:00' or
 [2000823317].[TimeStamp] BETWEEN '2014-12-31 19:00:00' AND '2014-12-31 19:05:00' or
 [2000823317].[TimeStamp] BETWEEN '2015-12-31 19:00:00' AND '2015-12-31 19:05:00' or
 [2000823317].[TimeStamp] BETWEEN '2016-12-31 19:00:00' AND '2016-12-31 19:05:00' or
 [2000823317].[TimeStamp] BETWEEN '2017-12-31 19:00:00' AND '2017-12-31 19:05:00' or
 [2000823317].[TimeStamp] BETWEEN '2018-12-31 19:00:00' AND '2018-12-31 19:05:00' or
 [2000823317].[TimeStamp] BETWEEN '2019-12-31 19:00:00' AND '2019-12-31 19:05:00'

SELECT  
    [2000823318].[TimeStamp], 
    [2000823318].[E_Total_Last] as "2000823318_E_Total_Last"

FROM [LIBPV_WB].[AD\30186656].[2000823318]
WHERE 
 [TimeStamp] BETWEEN '2010-12-31 19:00:00' AND '2010-12-31 19:05:00' or
 [TimeStamp] BETWEEN '2011-12-31 19:00:00' AND '2011-12-31 19:05:00' or
 [TimeStamp] BETWEEN '2012-12-31 19:00:00' AND '2012-12-31 19:05:00' or
 [TimeStamp] BETWEEN '2013-12-31 19:00:00' AND '2013-12-31 19:05:00' or
 [TimeStamp] BETWEEN '2014-12-31 19:00:00' AND '2014-12-31 19:05:00' or
 [TimeStamp] BETWEEN '2015-12-31 19:00:00' AND '2015-12-31 19:05:00' or
 [TimeStamp] BETWEEN '2016-12-31 19:00:00' AND '2016-12-31 19:05:00' or
 [TimeStamp] BETWEEN '2017-12-31 19:00:00' AND '2017-12-31 19:05:00' or
 [TimeStamp] BETWEEN '2018-12-31 19:00:00' AND '2018-12-31 19:05:00' or
 [TimeStamp] BETWEEN '2019-12-31 19:00:00' AND '2019-12-31 19:05:00'
```

The current output is two separate tables.
As seen below.

`+-------------------------+-------------------------+
|        TimeStamp        | 2000823317_E_Total_Last |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 2011-12-31 19:00:32.000 | 18981.512               |
| 2012-12-31 19:00:38.000 | 28900.006               |
| 2013-12-31 19:00:36.000 | 38431.747               |
| 2014-12-31 19:00:35.000 | 47849.842               |
| 2015-12-31 19:00:35.000 | 57313.301               |
| 2016-12-31 19:00:35.000 | 66487.605               |
| 2017-12-31 19:00:30.000 | 75611.001               |
| 2018-12-31 19:00:34.000 | 84582.739               |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+`

and

`+-------------------------+-------------------------+
|        TimeStamp        | 2000823318_E_Total_Last |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 2011-12-31 19:00:32.000 | 20704.789               |
| 2012-12-31 19:00:38.000 | 31622.242               |
| 2013-12-31 19:00:36.000 | 42268.048               |
| 2014-12-31 19:00:35.000 | 52779.672               |
| 2015-12-31 19:00:35.000 | 63317.686               |
| 2016-12-31 19:00:35.000 | 73649.122               |
| 2017-12-31 19:00:30.000 | 83923.87                |
| 2018-12-31 19:00:34.000 | 93977.001               |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+`

Desired output would have 3 columns with the first column being the TimeStamp
Followed by column2 = Data from First Table
and column3 = Data from the second table

`+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
|        TimeStamp        | 2000823317_E_Total_Last | 2000823318_E_Total_Last |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 2011-12-31 19:00:32.000 | 18981.512               | value                   |
| 2012-12-31 19:00:38.000 | 28900.006               | value                   |
| 2013-12-31 19:00:36.000 | 38431.747               | value                   |
| 2014-12-31 19:00:35.000 | 47849.842               | value                   |
| 2015-12-31 19:00:35.000 | 57313.301               | value                   |
| 2016-12-31 19:00:35.000 | 66487.605               | value                   |
| 2017-12-31 19:00:30.000 | 75611.001               | value                   |
| 2018-12-31 19:00:34.000 | 84582.739               |                         |
+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    [2000823317].[TimeStamp], 
    [2000823317].[E_Total_Last] as "2000823317_E_Total_Last",
    [2000823318].[E_Total_Last] as "2000823318_E_Total_Last"
FROM
    [LIBPV_WB].[AD\30186656].[2000823317]
LEFT JOIN 
    [LIBPV_WB].[AD\30186656].[2000823318] ON [2000823317].[TimeStamp] = [2000823318].[TimeStamp] 
WHERE 
 [2000823317].[TimeStamp] BETWEEN '2010-12-31 19:00:00' AND '2010-12-31 19:05:00' or
 [2000823317].[TimeStamp] BETWEEN '2011-12-31 19:00:00' AND '2011-12-31 19:05:00' or
 [2000823317].[TimeStamp] BETWEEN '2012-12-31 19:00:00' AND '2012-12-31 19:05:00' or
 [2000823317].[TimeStamp] BETWEEN '2013-12-31 19:00:00' AND '2013-12-31 19:05:00' or
 [2000823317].[TimeStamp] BETWEEN '2014-12-31 19:00:00' AND '2014-12-31 19:05:00' or
 [2000823317].[TimeStamp] BETWEEN '2015-12-31 19:00:00' AND '2015-12-31 19:05:00' or
 [2000823317].[TimeStamp] BETWEEN '2016-12-31 19:00:00' AND '2016-12-31 19:05:00' or
 [2000823317].[TimeStamp] BETWEEN '2017-12-31 19:00:00' AND '2017-12-31 19:05:00' or
 [2000823317].[TimeStamp] BETWEEN '2018-12-31 19:00:00' AND '2018-12-31 19:05:00' or
 [2000823317].[TimeStamp] BETWEEN '2019-12-31 19:00:00' AND '2019-12-31 19:05:00'
```

Procuded the following output

`+---+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
|   |            A            |            B            |            C            |
+---+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 1 | TimeStamp               | 2000823317_E_Total_Last | 2000823318_E_Total_Last |
| 2 | 2011-12-31 19:00:32.000 | 18981.512               | 20704.789               |
| 3 | 2012-12-31 19:00:38.000 | 28900.006               | 31622.242               |
| 4 | 2013-12-31 19:00:36.000 | 38431.747               | 42268.048               |
| 5 | 2014-12-31 19:00:35.000 | 47849.842               | 52779.672               |
| 6 | 2015-12-31 19:00:35.000 | 57313.301               | 63317.686               |
| 7 | 2016-12-31 19:00:35.000 | 66487.605               | 73649.122               |
| 8 | 2017-12-31 19:00:30.000 | 75611.001               | 83923.87                |
| 9 | 2018-12-31 19:00:34.000 | 84582.739               | 93977.001               |
+---+-------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+`